# jqGrid: Edit more than one cell using Cell Editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem. I'm using cell editing for jqGrid. I don't wish to change that for inline editing, since I need to keep it that way, only allowing to edit one cell at a time.

The thing is that I have a field which, after being edited, needs to force other cells to be edited. So, I need those cells to be open for edit if the user changes the first one to a certain value.

Is there any way to do this? I have tried with .jqGrid('editCell',...), but that way I only can do that with ONE cell at a time. And I can't ask for the next cell that has to be edited to force the 3rd and last to be edited, because it may happen that a user wants to edit that 2nd cell alone, which should result in this behaviour.

Any way to do this?

Thanks

**UPD**:

To make this more clear, I'll give an example. Supposse you have a table that lists the cars that people in your neighborhood has. It has 4 cells:

ID - CarCompany - Model - Year

Where ID is some identification field, CarCompany is the name of the company that manufactures the car, Model is the name of the model and Year is the year's model.

So for instance you have the following records:

0 - Ford - Focus - 2010

1 - Cadillac - Escalade - 2004

2 - Lamborghini - Diablo - 2012

The owners can change the car. They can change the Year, which shouldn't change any of the other cells (because they changed their cars for a newer version of their current car) and they can change the Model for another one with the same year. But if they change their cars for one from another company, you must update the Model and the Year (let's just assume you HAVE TO change the year). Therefore:

- If you change Year, that's the only cell you have to change
- If you change Model, that's the only cell you have to change
- But if you change CarCompany, you have to edit Model and Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct your problem you can use `afterSaveCell` callback or some other which better for your requirements (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#event_calling_stack)). You can test which column is modified and call `editCell` explicitly to suggest to edit depended cell. Probably you can use additionally custom validation rule (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example)) to be sure that the user really modify dependent cell to the correct value.

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DependentCellEditng.htm) shows how you can call `editCell` inside of `afterSaveCell` callback to implement the behavior which you need. The most important part of the code of the demo you will find below:

```
var carCompanyEditingMode = false;

$("#list").jqGrid({
    ...
    afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
        var $this = $(this), editedColName = this.p.colModel[iCol].name;
        if (editedColName === "carCompany") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.jqGrid("editCell", iRow, iCol + 1, true);
            }, 50);
            carCompanyEditingMode = true;
            return;
        }
        if (carCompanyEditingMode && editedColName === "model") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.jqGrid("editCell", iRow, iCol + 1, true);
            }, 50);
            return;
        }
        if (carCompanyEditingMode && editedColName === "year") {
            carCompanyEditingMode = false;
        }
    },
    beforeSelectRow: function () {
        // don't allow editing of another row if 
        // the carCompanyEditingMode is true
        return !carCompanyEditingMode;
    },
    afterRestoreCell: function (rowid, value, iRow, iCol) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (carCompanyEditingMode) {
            // continue editing of the same cell
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.jqGrid("editCell", iRow, iCol, true);
            }, 50);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I have only been able to use it to open ONE cell at a time. I need to have TWO cells opened when that condition is met. And I can concatenate editcell calls, because the other cells can be edited individually without having to behave this way.

Comment: @Heathcliff: Sorry, but I can't follow you. If directly after modifying the cell from one column (or if the user enter specific value in the cell) the user will have to modify the second cell from the row it seems me the same like you original requirement. With respect of `afterSaveCell` you can catch the end of editing of the first cell and call `editCell` with the second cell.

Comment: If I call 'editCell' with the first cell (the one that will require the user to edit TWO other cells) to edit the second cell, I won't be able to make it edit the third. I can't call 'editCell' in the afterSaveCell event of the second cell, because the individual edition of that cell doesn't require the user to edit the third cell; it will if the user edited the first cell and that's why it is editing the second. Unless there's something I can do to know in the afterCellEvent of the second cell if the user has edited the first and that's why he's editing the second, I can't use this.

Comment: @Heathcliff: Sorry, could you explain the problem on an example. In the previous comment you wrote about *two* cells in the next one you wrote about *third* cells. All descriptions looks not like clear algorithm: if ... then ... and so on. Could you describe the problem more clear? It would be probably better if you would describe an real example.

Comment: @Heathcliff: I included the demo which shows the most important parts of the implementation.